# Execute function specifically on CPU in Jax

Tags: python, memory, cpu, tpu, jax

I have a function that will instantiate a huge array and do other things. I am running my code on TPUs so my memory is limited.

How can I execute my function specifically on the CPU?

If I do:

```
y = jax.device_put(my_function(), device=jax.devices("cpu")[0])
```

I guess that `my_function()` is first executed on TPU and the result is put on CPU, which gives me memory error.

and using `jax.config.update('jax_platform_name', 'cpu')` at the beginning of my code seems to have no effect.

Also please note that I can't modify `my_function()`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly specify the device on which a function should be executed, use the `device` argument of `jax.jit`. For example (using a GPU runtime because it's the accelerator I have access to at the moment):

```py
import jax

gpu_device = jax.devices('gpu')[0]
cpu_device = jax.devices('cpu')[0]

def my_function(x):
  return x.sum()

x = jax.numpy.arange(10)

x_gpu = jax.jit(my_function, device=gpu_device)(x)
print(x_gpu.device())
# gpu:0

x_cpu = jax.jit(my_function, device=cpu_device)(x)
print(x_cpu.device())
# TFRT_CPU_0
```

This can also be controlled with the `jax.default_device` decorator around the call-site:

```py
with jax.default_device(cpu_device):
  print(jax.jit(my_function)(x).device())
  # TFRT_CPU_0

with jax.default_device(gpu_device):
  print(jax.jit(my_function)(x).device())
  # gpu:0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a guess here. I can't run it either so you may have to fiddle with it

```
with jax.default_device(jax.devices("cpu")[0]):
    y = my_function()
```

See the docs [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.default_device.html#jax.default_device) and [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#faq-data-placement).